# How to prevent Firefox from copying numbers or #'s when copy and pasting on a Mac?

Tags: macos, firefox, text-editor, copy-paste

When I copy and paste from a website that formats their text using <*li>, I get numbers or #'s when I paste into any text editor on my Mac (running Snow Leopard). Is there anything I can get that is equivalent to Windows Notepad, that will NOT copy the formatting, and just give me the text? Example of a site that I copy/paste from that gives me #'s or numbers:

http://themeshaper.com/wordpress-theme-sidebar-template/

Comment: Finally just decided to open websites in the Safari browser when I need to cut and paste. It's definitely limited to FireFox only, and there seems to be no work around. There was an add-on that supported cutting and pasting plain text only, but it apparently stopped working with FireFox 3.6. Here's hoping they release a new version soon!

Answer (score 1):

Use Paste As Plain Text in Word or Open Office or use a pure text editor like SciTE.

Comment: Tried the "past as plain text" in Word for Mac, still get the formatting. I think it's a Firefox issue?

Comment: Yep, tried that, it still pastes the characters. I found that Safari doesn't... so it IS a FireFox issue where it grabs the characters on the "copy".

Answer (score 0):

Most Cocoa applications that have a text editing interface have a **Paste and Match Style** option in the **Edit** menu. This will paste the text without pasting formatting.